# Potentially cancel all other submit handlers after my own

Tags: forms

I've unshifted my own submit handler to the #submit handler of a node form. I already have a validation handler, so I can't execute my cancelling submit handler there.

Maybe this makes more sense:

1. my validation
2. all other validation
3. my submit handler, which potentially kills the submit process to `form_state[rebuild] => TRUE` and try again
4. all other submit handlers

Is that possible? I can cancel submission if I put my submit logic in a validation, but that's too soon. It should only run when all validation passes.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question, but I can't quite follow what you are trying to accomplish?  Can you provide a little background as to what you need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your implementation of [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) is the last one to be called. Your implementation of [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) can then unshift one validation function and push a second validation function. The second validation function would then have complete information about whether other validation functions objected to saving the node (by calling [form_get_errors()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7)).

You can ensure that your your implementation of [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) is the last one to be called by implementing [hook_module_implements_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7)

Comment: DUH! Two validation functions! OMG I suck. My module has a high weight, so it'll be last. Thanks man.